# jQuery select on focus placeholder / val("")

Tags: jquery, select

I have several selects that allow captains to select positions for their players

```
$('.select_role').on('focus',function(){
            console.log("Test");
})  

$('.select_role').on('change',function(e){          
    $.ajax({
        url : './tournaments/hub/save_roster.php',
        type :'POST',
        data : {
            role_id : $(this).data('role'),
            tournament_id : '<?php echo $tournament_id;?>',
            team_id : '<?php echo $team_id;?>',
            user_id : $(this).val()
            },
        success : function(res){
            res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
            if(res.result == 0){
                toastr.warning(res.resp);                       
            }
            if(res.result == 1){
                toastr.success(res.resp);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

On an error message from my server script, the select should revert back to the previous val before the user changed it.

For some reason I can't get the focus on select element to work so I can't get the placeholder to revert back.

Reverting back is also impossible using a line like this

```
var ele = $(this)
ele.val("");
```

The select itself has value='0' as an option

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $this value in the scope that you are using it. $this in your code will refer not to the select element. Try:

```
    var ele = $('.select_role')
```

It can be also a smart decision to stop propagation of event as if you are in onchange and you change something so it will fire onchange again and so on and so forth to infinity.